# OSMDroid doesnt load maps that use API

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

i was trying to have a map that uses the OpenCycleMap but it doesn't load the map

```
 final String[] tileURLs = {"http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/",
                "http://b.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/",
                "http://c.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/"};

        final ITileSource OCM =
                new XYTileSource("Open Cycle Map",
                        0,
                        19,
                        512,
                        ".png?apikey=" + API_KEY,
                        tileURLs,
                        "from open cycle map");
        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        map.setTileSource(OCM);
```

Comment: I think the tile size is 256.  That is wat I used to use.  I had max zoom as 18 as well but that want break it untill you try that zoom.

Comment: Check if you have similar issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72541643/osmdroid-maps-is-not-loading-in-android-10-online-mode