# OsmDroid Maps is not loading in Android 10 (Online Mode)

Tags: android, maps, osmdroid

I'm working with osmdroid map in online mode. The map is loading properly in online mode in Android 11. But in Android 10 getting below issue.

```
java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to b.tile.openstreetmap.org not permitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below line in manifest file.

**android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For more info [android:usesCleartextTraffic Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)